# how to output into a tree like structure via Tree::DAG_Node?

Tags: perl, treeview, output, heapsort

I'm trying to write a program that can read from a file then put into a heap sort then output in a tree along with the sorted list. But I got stuck, instead of having the put be the numbers used in the heap sort, it just post 1-10 on one line then 1-9 on the next line. I'm really confused and I barely understand this language as it is. I put a example of the out below alone with the output I am hoping to have it draw.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.006;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tree::DAG_Node;


process_data(read_file('testing.txt'));
process_data((3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,6));

sub read_file{
    my($filename)=@_;
    my @data=();
    my @words;
    open(my $fh, "<", $filename)
        or die "Could not open file: $!\n";
    while(<$fh>){
    chomp;
    @words = split(' ');
    foreach my $word(@words){
    push @data, $word;
}

}
close $fh;

return @data;
}


sub heap_sort {
    my ($a) = @_;
    my $n = @$a;
    for (my $i = ($n - 2) / 2; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        down_heap($a, $n, $i);
    }
    for (my $i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        my $t = $a->[$n - $i - 1];
        $a->[$n - $i - 1] = $a->[0];
        $a->[0] = $t;
        down_heap($a, $n - $i - 1, 0);
    }
}

sub down_heap {
    my ($a, $n, $i) = @_;
    while (1) {
        my $j = max($a, $n, $i, 2 * $i + 1, 2 * $i + 2);
        last if $j == $i;
        my $t = $a->[$i];
        $a->[$i] = $a->[$j];
        $a->[$j] = $t;
        $i = $j;
    }


sub max {
    my ($a, $n, $i, $j, $k) = @_;
    my $m = $i;
    $m = $j if $j < $n && $a->[$j] > $a->[$m];
    $m = $k if $k < $n && $a->[$k] > $a->[$m];
    return $m;
}
}

sub draw_tree{
    my(@data)=@_;
    my $root = Tree::DAG_Node->new;
$root->name($_[0]);
$root->new_daughter->name($_) for (1..10);
my @names = @data;
my $count = 50;
for my $n ($root->daughters) {
    for (split //, $names[$count++]) {
        $n->new_daughter->name($_)
    }
}
print map "$_\n", @{$root->draw_ascii_tree};
}

sub process_data{
    my(@data)=@_;
    my @a = @data;
    print "@a\n";
    print "\n";
    heap_sort(\@a);
    draw_tree(@a);
    print "\n";
    print "@a\n";
    print "\n";

}
```

here is the output I get 
[CMD output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfZDj.png)

Output I am expecting:
(using example data)

1 1 9 4 5

```
   1
   |
 1 ----- 9
 |      
 /\ 
4 5
```

1 1 4 5 9

Comment: What output do you get?  What output are you expecting?  Update your question with the answers.

Comment: @xxfelixxx I update my question with the output I am looking for, and a picture of the CMD output that I am getting so far

Comment: @xxfelixxx my question has been updated